# Push After Cherry pick in Git

Tags: git, gerrit

I have two branches, B1 and B2 , I am trying to cherry pick a commit with hash x from B1 into B2, what I've done:

```
- git checkout B2
- git cherry-pick x
```

I got some conflicts, I fixed them and did:

```
- git add .
- git cherry-pick --continue
```

now I am trying to push the changes after the cherry-pick commit, I keep getting this error:

```
Branch written in Commit x is incorrect.
        Branch in commit: B1
        Actual branch: B2)
```

I've read about the cherry-pick command and what it does, but I can't figure out why it says that the commit is made in branch B1 and not B2 .

Comment: Are you sure that's coming from Git and not a [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)? Or perhaps a tool like Gerrit?

Comment: @Schwern I'm not sure, but what difference does it make ? as I understand it, Gerrit is the client side of the VCS . Thanks .

Comment: I dont think the error message is coming from git. I guess the cherry-pick was successful. The error message looks line a custom server-side pre-receive hook.

Comment: @MohamedTaher Gerrit uses Git, but it is not Git. We need to know what tools you're using, and modifications which have been made to it, to help you out. I'm guessing when you did the cherry pick you kept the same [Change-Id](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/user-changeid.html) in the commit message. That can confuse earlier versions of Gerrit. What version of Gerrit are you using?